# My css doesn't work well in my main html page

Tags: html, css, program-entry-point

I want to change my main HTML page.  I would like to have the login section at the right side, the paragraph in the middle and the header at the top and in the middle. I tried to change the code in the CSS but nothing.

How it is now:
[image: main now]

How I would like to be:

[image: the desired main]

My current website code:

```js
function resetForm() {
  // clearing selects
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++)
    selects[i].selectedIndex = 0;

  return false;
}
window.load(resetForm());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 200px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff9900;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
div.container#login {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
div.container #div.content_right #div.login #inputfield {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: right;
}
div.login#input[type="password"] {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
div.login#input[type="reset"] {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 70%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #ff9933;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="header"></div>statistics</div>
<!--End of Header-->

<!--Pragraph in the center-->
<div id="p">
  <p>
    Some text
  </p>
</div>
<!--End of Pragraph-->

<div id="content">
  <div id="content_right">
    <div id="login">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="username" size="30" />
        <br />
        <br/>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="inputfield" type="password" name="password" size="30" />
        <br />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
      </form>
      <!--End of Login-->
    </div>
    <!--End of content right-->
  </div>
  <!--End of content-->
</div>


</div>
<!--End of Container-->
<div id="footer">
  footer
</div>
<!--End of Footer-->
```

Comment: You're not closing your `<div id="header">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to research the `display` CSS property, this will go a long way to helping you reach what you want.

see http://learnlayout.com/display.html and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

### P.s

*please note that the OP was edited so this no longer displays the page was set as HTML5*

In HTML5, which you have, the character encoding is displayed differently:

<strike>`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`</strike>

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

### P.s.s

As Jamie Barker rightly pointed out, your `<div id="header">` is not closed. this will cause problems later on. Just add a `</div>` underneath the header element.

### P.s.s.s

Finally, your CSS:

```
div.container#login {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
div.container #div.content_right #div.login #inputfield {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: right;
}
```

These are all referencing using the period (dot) `.` or the `#` symbol. But `div.container` means **"the div containing the container class"** but this is not so because the "container" identifier is infact an `id` NOT a `class` so you need to adjust all your CSS to reference `id` rather than `class` as so:

`#this is an id identifier in CSS`

`.this is a class identifier in CSS`

You also do not need to reference the div tag itself, so replace the quoted CSS with this:

```
#container#login {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#container #div.content_right #div.login #inputfield {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: do I delete 'div.login#input[type="password"]' this code? and the </div> in the header it  was a typo

Comment: no, you rename it properly: it becomes:`#login input[type=password]` (can you see why? The Input type password within the login id area)

Comment: @mapr18 looking at your code again it's easier to reference the password field as: `.inputfield[type=password]` using the call to the class rather than any id .

Comment: I also want the labels to move to the left a little bit, how can I do it?

Comment: changing their left side padding and/or margin values.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you aren't using absolute positioning over float?

Place all of your html within a container div and apply the following css:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

All of your html elements within the div then use position: absolute and left and top attributes to position them however you want. If you need to give the container a fixed height and / or width.

Comment: surely giving "the container a fixed height and / or width" is a good reason not to use absolute positioning? how about on a phone screen only 320px wide versus a laptop screen 1600 wide? I think absolute positioning is not a good method to get into with the range of devices that webpages can be viewed on....

Comment: Agree with Martin. Relative/Absolute positioning can cause a big headache unless you really know what you're doing. Should really only be used in "Needs must" circumstances.

Comment: I did say fixed height / width if needed. Also if he wants this website to be responsive that's another ball park completely, I agree that using absolute positioning with @media queries is best avoided, but in this instance for a simple login page, it should be sufficient to position things how he wants :)

Comment: surely we should be showing people how to do things *properly*, rather than how to "do things just good enough to get past their current problem and then give them new problems down the line"? Just saying. You might as well say for the ease of getting what he wants, that he bangs the whole page into a table layout......

Comment: Completely irrelevant comment, solution was to his problem as described, not based on predictions of what he may want to do further down the line.

Comment: So why not recommend he sets his layout using a table? that would also solve his problem? Anyway, it doesn't matter. I can feel I'm getting arsey with it and I don't want to be. I don't mean to be. :-(